# How to use Django's index_together for query both with filter and order_by?

Tags: python, mysql, django, indexing

I have a problem with building right index for my query.
I have a model like this:

```
from django.db import models  

class Record(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, related_name='records')
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, db_index=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        index_together = (
            ('user', 'time'),
            ('action', 'user', 'time'),
        )
```

As you can see, there are two custom indexes for this model.

If I wanna get all records, related to specific user, filtered by `time`, I use this query: `user.records.filter(time__gt=some_moment)`. It works OK and uses first custom index (according to [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/)).

Now, in my situation result must be sorted by `action`. I use this query: `user.records.filter(time__gt=some_moment).order_by('action')`.
But, although an appropriate index exists, it is not used.

What am I doing wrong? How to build correct index for this query?
Django version = 1.8.4, all migrations are applied, database backend = mysql.

UPD: there is my query:

```
SELECT *** FROM `appname_record`
  WHERE (`appname_record`.`user_id` = 1896158 AND 
  `appname_record`.`time` > '2015-10-19 06:39:30.992790') 
  ORDER BY `appname_record`.`action_id` ASC
```

there is full django toolbar explanation:

```
ID: 1  
SELECT_TYPE: SIMPLE  
TABLE: appname_record  
TYPE: ALL  
POSSIBLE_KEYS: 
   appname_record_user_id_3214bab8a46891cc_idx, appname_record_07cc694b  
KEY: None  
KEY_LEN: None  
REF: None  
ROWS: 240  
EXTRA: Using where; Using filesort
```

There is mysql `show create table appname_record;` part about keys:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `appname_record_action_id_3e42ba1d5288899c_idx` (`action_id`, `user_id`,`time`),
KEY `appname_record_user_id_3214bab8a46891cc_idx` (`user_id`,`time`),
KEY `appname_record_07cc694b` (`time`),
```

So it seems like right index isn't even in possible keys.

Comment: While this looks like a django problem at first glance this is really a mysql problem. What you should post is the explain output (which can be accessed from the debug toolbar). ALso please update the post to give the exact model (saying it's this but a foreignkey instead is confusing)

Comment: Try changing columns order to `('action', 'user', 'time')`

Comment: @e4c5 sorry, made the model just like real one. Also added details about django explanation and mysql `create table` query.

Comment: @pista329 thanx for your advice, tried to change the order, but it didn't work.

Comment: how many rows all together in your table?

Comment: @e4c5 right now -- just 500, for 2 or 3 users. But on production database there will be millions of them, and they will be used all the time.

Comment: @e4c5 I tried to build just any query, which will use this 3-column index, but all of them ignored it and used 2-column. Have no idea why. So I just dropped 2-column index (with `user_id` and `time`), and now both queries use the second one. It is not very elegant way to solve the problem, but it worked. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a query does not use any indexes at all, that's often because there isn't enough data in the table for an index to be really useful. However with 500 records there is a good chance that an index ought to come into play.

In the query that you have used, the `appname_record_user_id_3214bab8a46891cc_idx` is indeed a likely candidate but it's still not used. Why? because your query apparently causes the database to look at approximately half the table, as such an index cannot speed things up.

You seem to be on the right track with dropping one index. Two many similar indexes aren't really usefull either. I would try this index instead:

```
class Meta:
    index_together = (
        ('user', 'time','action'),
    )
```

The difference here is in the order of the fields. This is [important](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the
>   columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the
>   first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify
>   the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single
>   composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same
>   table.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation, now my "just drop smaller index" solution impact doesn't seem so magic anymore

Answer (score 6):

For the new versions of Django, using Index class meta over index_together meta options is suggested.

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
            models.Index(fields=['first_name'], name='first_name_idx'),
        ]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#index-together

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, it is not elegant, but it worked for me. Since I couldn't build any query, which will use 3-column index, I jush dropped a 2-column, so now both of my queries use 3-column. Have no idea, why it was ignored previously. Maybe, some complex mysql optimizations.