# How to create a Django Model Index for an OR query

Tags: mysql, django, indexing

Within a manager for a class I have the following method to only select objects wanted in certain instances.

```
def active(self):
    query = Q(
        Q(is_active=True, care_over_65=True, is_provider=False)
        & Q(
            Q(service_care_home=True)
            | Q(service_home_care=True)
            | Q(service_live_in_care=True)
        )
    ) | Q(is_active=True, service_retirement_village=True, is_provider=False)
    return self.get_queryset().filter(query)
```

Is it possible to write an Index for this within the model to improve performance?  At the moment I have specified each of these fields separately (as individual indexes) and all together as a single index

```
        models.Index(
            fields=[
                'is_active', 'care_over_65', "is_provider",'service_care_home','service_home_care','service_live_in_care', '-is_premium', 'name'
            ]
        ),
```

but this seems to make no difference to performance.

It is running on MySQL8

Comment: Try  'index_together' , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186938/how-to-use-djangos-index-together-for-query-both-with-filter-and-order-by

Comment: Please show us the _generated SQL_ and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I, for one, don't know the obfuscation involved in the hundred frameworks such as Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the way indexes work **don't** support OR, as the idea of the index to look for matching rows from left column to right column. so, it is advised to replace such query with a **UNIION** query so each query is evaluated independently and the result is aggregated before returning the result to the client.

Example

Rather than writing

```
select * from Table where colA='A' or ColB='X'
```

This shall be written as

```
select * from Table where colA='A' UNION select * from Table ColB='X'
```

This needs 2 indices to be done, One on colA and another on colB

P.S This is not supported in django and has to be managed manually.

Comment: please give an example

Comment: Corollary:  When performance becomes the primary concern, it is time to abandon the framework and learn SQL.